# Azure stored procedure not executing when call sp_execute_remote

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures

I try to do a across database query in AZURE SQL elastic pools but it's not working.

My stored procedure is:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE  [dbo].[CreateNewSurveyQuestion]
    @QuestionString varchar(MAX)
 AS
    INSERT INTO CTRL_Survey(SurveyQuestion)
    VALUES (@QuestionString)

    --create new survey in new qm
    EXEC sp_execute_remote  
        N'QCentralDS',  
        N'INSERT INTO [dbo].[SurveyTbl]([Question], [IsActive], [CreateDate])
          VALUES(@QuestionStringValue, 1, GETDATE())' 
        , N'@QuestionStringValue varchar(300)'
        , @QuestionStringValue = @QuestionString
```

2. EXEC stored procedure [not working with error message below]

   ```
   EXEC [dbo].[CreateNewSurveyQuestion]
           @QuestionString = N'Add a new question'
   ```

Error message:

> Msg 64, Level 20, State 0, Line 1
>   A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.)

I am sure all EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE are correct. And I can run this part in my SQL Server Management Studio successfully.

```
    EXEC sp_execute_remote  
        N'QCentralDS',  
        N'INSERT INTO [dbo].[SurveyTbl]([Question], [IsActive], [CreateDate])
          VALUES(@QuestionStringValue, 1, GETDATE())' 
        , N'@QuestionStringValue varchar(300)'
        , @QuestionStringValue = @QuestionString
```

Is there any issue with this mode of work, or exists another way to do it?

Comment: The message suggests that there is a problem with the credential you're using in the external data source, or with the querying database connecting to the target database.  Are both of your databases on Azure, and are they on the same Azure Database Server?

Comment: Yes they are both in the same Azure SQL server, also I put them in a  SQL elastic pools